# Only show a child element when list item has a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this carousel. The list item with class `indicator` shows where I currently am in the carousel and is on top of the other list items with a position absolute. As you can see every other list item contains an anchor.

Right now every list item has an anchor as its child.

Now I only want to show the anchor when the list item has the class `main-pos`.

```
<ul class="carousel">
  <li class="indicator"></li>

  <li class="items main-pos" onclick="currentSlide(1)" id="1">
    <a href="#about">item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="items right-pos" onclick="currentSlide(2)" id="2">
    <a href="#">item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(3)" id="3">
    <a href="#">item 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(4)" id="4">
    <a href="#">item 4</a>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(5)" id="5">
    <a href="#">item 5</a>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(6)" id="6">
    <a href="#">item 6</a>
  </li>
  <li class="items left-pos" onclick="currentSlide(7)" id="7">
    <a href="#">item 7</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I attempted to revise your question for clarity. Speaking in code like you were isn't a great approach. However, someone else explained that I may have misinterpreted your intent. Please revise again, using common terminology, so we're all clear. I now suspect that you're asking how to remove the anchor tags from around your label text except when it's active. Is that correct? If so, it requires scripting and you need to show an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding extra spans which are displayed in cases where you don't want anchor tag

I have added a angular stackblitz but it is not using anything angular specific

Here is the html and css for your reference

```
  <ul class="carousel">
  <li class="indicator"></li>

  <li class="items main-pos" onclick="currentSlide(1)" id="1">
      <a href="#about">item 1</a>
      <span>item 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="items right-pos" onclick="currentSlide(2)" id="2">
      <a href="#">item 2</a>
      <span>item 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(3)" id="3">
      <a href="#">item 3</a>
      <span>item 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(4)" id="4">
      <a href="#">item 4</a>
      <span>item 4</span>
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(5)" id="5">
      <a href="#">item 5</a> 
      <span>item 5</span>                                          
  </li>
  <li class="items back-pos" onclick="currentSlide(6)" id="6">
      <a href="#">item 6</a>
      <span>item 6</span>                  
  </li>
  <li class="items left-pos" onclick="currentSlide(7)" id="7">
      <a href="#">item 7</a>
      <span>item 7</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
.back-pos a, .right-pos a, .left-pos a {
    display: none;
}
.main-pos span {
   display: none;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fehftq

Comment: OMG thanx i was thinking to damn hard

Answer (score 0):

Isn't as simple as this?

```
.items a {display: none;}
.items.main-pos a {display: block;}
.items.main-pos span {display: none;}
```

Comment: nothing will appear not even the item names if it is applied to a, I might be wrong but from what I understood is that @Marc doesn't want links but he needs the text in all cases

Answer (score -1):

You can use and if function in your code to check if the element matches the class, and then if it does, then do something.

Here's what I mean:

```js
let carousel = document.getElementById("carousel")
if (carousel.classList.contains(class);) {
  //do something
} else {
return: null;
}
```